# There appears to be an error in Calendar.php

Tags: php, calendar, google-api-php-client

I was trying to set the start and end times while using an event as defined by `Calendar.php`.

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setStart($item->start->dateTime);
```

My code halted at this line. So, I took a look at `Calendar.php` from the google-api-php and found that the code said:

```
2999: public function setStart(Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime $start)
3000: {
3001:    $this->start = $start;
3002: }
```

From here I discovered that `$start` was a member of the `Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime` class, so my simple dateTime string was not going to work.  I then went to look for how `$this->start` is defined.  It is not for the class `Google_Service_Calendar_Event`.  The only things defined were:

```
2690: protected $sourceDataType = '';
2691: protected $startType = 'Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime';
2692: protected $startDataType = '';
```

So, I suspect that `this->start` that I found in the function `setStart` should actually be `this->startType`. However, I am such a noob when it comes to this Google API that I thought I should ask the experts. Any thoughts as to how to set the start and end times for a Calendar event and write it to a Google Calendar?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "halted"? What errors are you getting?

Comment: while running the code in my webbrowser, it stop providing output after it reaches the $event->setStart code. I'm not surprised by this since I am clearly giving it data it doesn't expect.

Comment: Do you have errors turned on? If not then put this at the top of your script: `error_reporting(-1);ini_set('display_errors','On');`.